# UICollectionViewで「insertItemsAtIndexPaths:」完了時のタイミングを取る方法はありますか？

Tags: swift

`UICollectionView`で
`insertItemsAtIndexPaths:`が完了した後のタイミングで
collectionview全体の表示を更新したいです。

`insertItemsAtIndexPaths:`完了時のタイミングを取る方法はありますか？

```
func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(scrollView: UIScrollView)
```

で試してみましたが、このメソッドは呼ばれないようです。

今の時点では、`insertItemsAtIndexPaths:`された時に
`NStimer`を作って,0.35秒後に発火するようにしています。
あまりスマートではないと思います。

よろしくお願いします。